Не отправляются сообщения в форме Flask
Есть код:
# Конфигурация для Flask-Mail
app.secret_key = 'my_secret_key'
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.yandex.ru'  # Укажите ваш SMTP сервер
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 587  # Порт для подключения
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'abram-742@yandex.ru'  # Ваш email
user = app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'abram-742@yandex.ru'
print(user)
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = '#'  # Ваш пароль
parol = app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'turandott_23'  # Ваш пароль
print(parol)
app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'] = 'abram-742@yandex.ru'  # Отправитель

mail = Mail(app)

Есть обработчик:
@app.route('/contacts', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contacts():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form.get('name')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        message = request.form.get('message')

        # Проверка на заполненность полей
        if not name or not email or not message:
            flash("Все поля должны быть заполнены!", 'error')
            return redirect('/contacts')

        # Отправка электронной почты
        if send_email(name, email, message):
            flash("Ваше сообщение было отправлено!", 'success')
        else:
            flash("Произошла ошибка при отправке сообщения. Попробуйте позже.", 'error')

        return redirect('/contacts')

    return render_template('contacts.html')

При попытке отправить сообщение выдаёт следующую ошибку:

(535, b'5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: Invalid user or password!')

Хотя я проверял все данные указаны правильно(логин, пароль) Вопрос: если кто знает причину данной ошибки или сталкивался с подобной ситуацией прошу подсказать.

Вы зачем все логины-пароли выдали ))

Как выглядит html-страница "contacts.html"? Приложите её код. И покажите код функции send_email. Всё это прямо в вопросе.
